# Get All Reviews From Amazon? Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, amazon-product-api

I am trying to read all the reviews of a product from python. I have a script, but it does not work.

```
parser = html.fromstring(page_response)
XPATH_AGGREGATE = '//span[@id="acrCustomerReviewText"]'
XPATH_REVIEW_SECTION_1 = '//div[@data-hook="reviews-content"]'
XPATH_REVIEW_SECTION_2 = '//div[@data-hook="review"]'

XPATH_AGGREGATE_RATING = '//table[@id="histogramTable"]//tr'
XPATH_PRODUCT_NAME = '//h1//span[@id="productTitle"]//text()'
XPATH_PRODUCT_PRICE  = '//span[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]/text()'

raw_product_price = parser.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_PRICE)
product_price = ''.join(raw_product_price).replace(',','')

raw_product_name = parser.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_NAME)
product_name = ''.join(raw_product_name).strip()
total_ratings  = parser.xpath(XPATH_AGGREGATE_RATING)
reviews = parser.xpath(XPATH_REVIEW_SECTION_1)
if not reviews:
    reviews = parser.xpath(XPATH_REVIEW_SECTION_2)
```

The page is https://www.amazon.com/productreviews/'+asin+"/, where asin is an ID (eg, B0718Y23CQ). I get nothing in reviews. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I have to be honest, I don't know where are some of the paths that you use, because I can't find them. I have redone your code to try to help:

```
from lxml import html 
import requests
import json
asin = 'B0718Y23CQ'
page_response = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/'+ asin)
parser = html.fromstring(page_response.content)
reviews_html = parser.xpath('//div[@class="a-section review"]')
reviews_arr = []
for review in reviews_html:
    review_dic = {}
    review_dic['title'] = review.xpath('.//a[@data-hook="review-title"]/text()')
    review_dic['rating'] = review.xpath('.//a[@class="a-link-normal"]/@title')
    review_dic['author'] = review.xpath('.//a[@data-hook="review-author"]/text()')
    review_dic['date'] = review.xpath('.//span[@data-hook="review-date"]/text()')
    review_dic['purchase'] = review.xpath('.//span[@data-hook="avp-badge"]/text()')
    review_dic['review_text'] = review.xpath('.//span[@data-hook="review-body"]/text()')
    review_dic['helpful_votes'] = review.xpath('.//span[@data-hook="helpful-vote-statement"]/text()')
    reviews_arr.append(review_dic)
print(json.dumps(reviews_arr, indent = 4))
```

The output scheme is:

```
{
        "title": [
            "I find it very useful, I use for anything I need"
        ],
        "rating": [
            "5.0 out of 5 stars"
        ],
        "author": [
            "Nicoletta Delon"
        ],
        "date": [
            "on January 2, 2018"
        ],
        "purchase": [
            "Verified Purchase"
        ],
        "review_text": [
            "I like this a lot. I use it a lot. It's a medium to small size but it holds a lot."
        ],
        "helpful_votes": [
            "\n      One person found this helpful.\n    "
        ]
    }
```

Now you have to clean the results, remove them from the lists, prevent that the element can be empty and I think you'll have what you need.
To get all the reviews, you have to iterate the pages, adding `?pageNumber=1` to the link, and iterating the number. You can use proxies for prevent the blocking of the ip, in case you're going to make many requests.

Comment: I still get "unable to find reviews"

Comment: @Lincoln can you put your output, and the link of the product? because 
I've tried the code and it works for me

Comment: Yes. My output is just an error: ValueError: unable to find reviews in page. The link to the product is the same one I gave in the example: "https://www.amazon.com/productreviews/B0718Y23CQ/&pageNumber=1"

Comment: @Lincoln if you go to the link you can see that is malformated, https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B0718Y23CQ?pageNumber=1

Comment: I fixed that, am still getting an error. The reviews_html array is empty.